# Find and Repleace with notepad++ and Wildcards/Placeholders

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

Please does someone know how to do the following **search and repleace** with notepad++ ?

- from: to_timestamp('01-JAN-16 11.00.00.000000000 AM','DD-MON-RR
  HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),
- to: str_to_date('01-JAN-16 11.00.00.000000000 AM', '%d-%b-%y
  %h.%i.%s.%f000 %p')

--

- from: to_date('20-10-2014 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
- to: str_to_date('20-10-2014 00:00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'),

The first string with the date is variable, if there are better tools than notepad++ for this, I am happy about recommendations,

Comment: Could you please post an example?

Comment: i want to search for: to_date('20-10-2014 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and replace it with str_to_date('20-10-2014 00:00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'). The tricky part is, that the first part in the search to_date('XX-XX-XXXX XX:XX:XX,..) is variable.

Comment: Try  to_date('[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ to replace, hit Ctrl+H to open the Replace menu.

Then if you check the "Regular expression" button you can create capture groups for the above.

Comment: Thanks but my regexp knowledge is limited for such a query (; So i thought there is some way to use Placeholders.

Comment: Regex is what your looking for; have a look at this site, one can learn, create, test regex http://www.regexr.com